# How to get the number of child elements?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to count how many element with the class .test within my div. I have

```
<div id='testDiv'>ddd 
   <div class='test'> 111<div> another div </div></div>
   <div class='test'> 222</div>
   <div class='test'> 333</div>
   more...
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
if($('#testDiv.test').length>5){
   alert('haha');
}
```

I can't seem to get the correct number of div with the class name test.

Comment: `$('#testDiv.test')` you are trying to find a div with attribute id=testDiv and in the same div must be the attribute css=test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the selector like following:

```
$('#testDiv .test').length
```

Put an `space` between `#testDiv` and `.test`.

`$('#testDiv .test')` will find out the direct children of `#testDiv` who has `class=test`.

***Full Code:***

```
if( $('#testDiv .test').length > 5 ){
   alert('haha');
}
```

#### Note

`$('#testDiv.test')` means you are selection some element which has both `id=testDiv` and `class=test` like `<div id="testDiv" class="test"></div>`.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a space between `#testDiv` and `.test`

```
$('#testDiv .test').length
```

What you have is like below,

```
$('#testDiv.test') //- element with ID testDiv and class test  
//<div id="testDiv" class="test">...</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're searching for an element that has ID of `testDiv` **AND** a class of `test`, e.g.

```
<div id="testDiv" class="test">
```

You need

```
$('#testDiv .test")
           ^--- note the space
```

instead. With the space, it'll be all nodes with class 'test' that are children of the node with id testDiv.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#testDiv').children('.test').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

- `$('#testDiv .test")` This will count all *immediate* descendants--if it's a child of a child, you will not count it.
- `$('#testDiv').find('.test')` or simply `$('#testDiv, .test')` will find ALL descendants.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I am writing 3 cases:

**Method 1:**
If .test is direct child to #testdiv

In this you chould use [.children](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Eg:

```
$("#testdiv").children(".test")
```

This will give you array of elements with class 'test'. In javascript to find size of array we use length property.
So
  $("#testdiv").children(".test").length
will do your job.

**Method 2:**
Similarly to find all elements with 'test' class in your #testdiv you can use [.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) callback. This approach should be used when you don't know nested level of '.test' element because it is not optimized way.
Eg:
    $("#testdiv").find(".test")
This will give you array of elements. Use same thing .length to find size of array.

**Method 3:**
You can also try using:

```
$("#testdiv .test")
```

This will work same as method:2 but it is less optimized.

**Your mistake:**
You tried using following syntax

```
$("#testdiv.test")
```

This selector gives you element with class 'test' and id 'testdiv'.

Thanks